# Readable stream from blank pdf file (without text)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, buffer

In my code, I retrieve a PDF file from Amazon S3, and I create a readable stream from it. I then proceed to read the file in chunks with the intention of determining its MIME type. While this approach typically functions as expected, I encounter a problem when the PDF file lacks text or contains only minimal text content. It appears that the reading stream does not terminate appropriately in such cases.

```
const stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()

const fileType = await new Promise((resolve) => {
            stream.once('data', (chunk) => {
                resolve(fromBuffer(chunk))
            })
        })
```

Is there a way to stop this stream?

Note: I attempted to use the destroy() method immediately after reading data, but I encountered an error because the stream is still being used at some point after data reading. I also tried using the end() method, but it didn't have the desired effect in stopping the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the abort method does not exist anymore